# SKLabelNode under SKSpriteNode crash application swift

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, nodes

How can I update `SKLabelNode` under the `SKNode` programmatically? Application crashes when I'm trying to do it. Please help me, here are some screenshots:

Crash Error

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Don't add code as images, include error message you get (as text).

Comment: alright i have added text also

Comment: Ok, what about code?

Comment: @barbsan The OP could also use `enumerateNodesWithName` or `sound.childNode(withName...` I think.

Answer (score 1):

it's because "On" is not a child of SKScene, its parent is "Sound" which is shown in right side bar! so you wanna access the "On" while it is not there.

Comment: then how i can do this ?

Comment: change the parent to SKScene